# Injecting component causes Unknown provider $scopeProvider

Tags: angularjs

I want to call a function from one component in another one.

I have a `NavigationComponent` which injects another component called `MapComponent:

```
@Inject('MapComponent')
```

The MapComponent has the @Service decorator:

```
@Service('CustomerService', 'MapComponent')
```

In the MapComponent I want to use `$scope.watch` so I inject $scope:

```
@Inject('$scope')
```

And in the constructor of the MapComponent I have:

```
constructor(private $scope: IMenuScope) {
    this.$scope.$watch('x', (newValue, oldValue, s) => {
        // something happens
    });
}
```

When I run this app I get:

> angular.js:15567 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- MapComponent

When I remove:

```
@Inject('MapComponent')
```

From NavigationComponent the app renders correctly.

So when I inject MapComponent in NavigationComponent I get a Unknown provider error in the MapComponent. But without the injection the MapComponent works fine.

Comment: Can you help me with the `angularJS` version where you are able to use `@Inject` with AngularJS ? I cant find it over their doc page

Comment: Seems like you can't inject a component in a component. Same like you can't inject a controller in a controller. Also using AngularJS 1.7 with Typescript. That's very close to the Angular experience.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to inject $scope into service, this wont work.